# Checking the channel in the channel entries tag

Tags: channel-entries, ee3, ifelse

What I am trying to do is combine the output of 2 channels. They both have an image with a different name so I am trying to check the channel to determine the which image I need to output. Code below.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="work"  dynamic="no" limit="3"}
            <a href="http://leith.co.uk/getting-blokes-thinking-drinking/">
               {if channel=="work"}
                <div class="latest-post latest-column" style="background-image:url({work_main_image});">
                {if:elseif channel == 'latest'}
                   <div class="latest-post latest-column" style="background-image:url({latest_main_image});">
               {/if}
                <div class="latest-title"> {title}</div>
                </div>
            </a>
        {/exp:channel:entries}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using

```
channel_short_name == "work"
```

You can find the short name in the list of channels.

Also in your channel tag, you'll need to specify both channels.

```
channel="work|latest"
```